# Spring Web MVC always returns Error 500

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have a problem, with a Spring MVC base site,.
it returns the Error 500 in the very first access to any page, but it works perfectly for the next request. any idea how to trace it,.?

Comment: just did it, TIm, thank you,.
where is the log take plave,.?

Comment: That depends on your application and servlet engine. If you're trying to debug an error with a web application (_any web application_) then step 1 is - go read the documentation for your technologies and work out how to turn on logging. You won't have much success solving any other problems until you get decent log output.

Comment: You could start reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133153/what-is-debug-logging-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really giving a lot to go on.  My first immediate guess would be that this is related to not having a session already open but is just a stab in the dark.  Tim is correctly, without logging in place you are going to have a difficult time finding this.