# Not Rendering Multiple JSP pages in Spring mvc Intellij

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I have made a project with Spring MVC in IntelliJ. I have made two pages `showForm.jsp` and `processForm.jsp`. I am trying to get studentName from `showForm` page and appear it on the `processForm` page. I have tried several things but every time I run my application I always get `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`. If anyone can help me, please.

**here is my HelloWorldController class**

```
 package com.SpringMVCProject;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

@RequestMapping("/showForm")
public String showForm(){

    return "showForm";
}

@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String processForm(){

    return "processForm";
}
```

**showForm.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World- Input Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/processForm.jsp" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="studentName" placeholder="What is your name?">
    <input type="submit">



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**processForm**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Process Form</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World of Spring!

<br>
<br>
    Student Name: ${param.studentName}

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the URL you are trying to access? what is the context path?

Comment: This is the URL I want to access after clicking submit button on showForm http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCLearning_war_exploded/processForm.jsp

Comment: I have mentioned this in applicationContext.xml but it does not make a difference sorry too long to post the whole file but                                                               <context:component-scan base-package="com.SpringMVCProject">
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>

Comment: can you try replacing  SpringMVCLearning_war_exploded with project name?

Comment: How is your `web.xml` looks like?

Comment: Tried replacing with project name it did not work. I can access it by typing http://localhost:8080/showForm.jsp but as soon as I click on submit it comes back with HTTP 404 page

Comment: Like below <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> </listener>
<servlet><servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet><servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>  </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app> Thank you btw

Comment: why is `url-pattern` here `<url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>` .. enable logging to understand why is it failing  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133153/what-is-debug-logging-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Unsure why URL pattern is like that but I will look into logging. Thank you so much

Comment: The above tells match all the URL patterns ends with .form. Try replacing .from with /